# Программа для нахождения синонимов русских слов python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

Я пишу код, который выводит синонимы к словам:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

synonyms = []

for syn in wordnet.synsets("hi"):
    for lm in syn.lemmas():
             synonyms.append(lm.name())
print (set(synonyms))
```

Но, данный код выводит синонимы только к английским словам, а как сделать так чтобы выводил и для русских слов?

Comment: Думаю что не ошибусь, если скажу что есть 2 пути. 1) Найти либу которая это делает, 2) Написать такую либу самому

Comment: Решение "в лоб". Скачать словарь синонимов, загнать его в БД и вытягивать их из БД с учетом морфологии и контекста.

Comment: попробуйте https://pypi.org/project/PyDictionary/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

можно перевести так:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator

synonyms = []

for syn in wordnet.synsets("hi"):
    for lm in syn.lemmas():
             synonyms.append(lm.name())

rusynonyms = []

for synonym in synonyms:
    rusynonyms.append(GoogleTranslator(source='en', target='ru').translate(synonym))

print(rusynonyms)
```

Comment: переводить синонимы. вы серьезно? ) Это ж такой ужас будет, если учесть "огромную омонимичность" английского языка...

Comment: хоть какой-то результат, других вариантов пока не нашел, ну можно с русской бд спарсить. Но с вами согласен

Comment: Идея так-себе, а вот за наводку на либу `deep_translator`  спасибо.

Comment: Это самое гениальное решение